# Angular Component not always loading data correctly

Tags: angular, http, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm having some problems loading my Angular Component.
In this Component, I retrieve some API data by using my data-service.
In this data service, I have a function getAllData().

```
getAllData()
{
return this._http.get<IData[]>(this.apiUrl)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

In my Component, in my contructor, I send along my data service.

```
constructor(private _dataService: DataService) {}
```

In the ngOnInit function in my component, I use the data service to retrieve my data:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
 this._dataService.getAllData()
   .subscribe(
   data => this.data = JSON.stringify(data),
   error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
   () => 
   {
    // In here, I use the received data

    let root = JSON.parse(this.data);
    let ndx = crossfilter(root);
    let all = ndx.groupAll();

   // Here I create multiple dimensions in the data, to create charts 
      where you can filter through. Eventually I call the 
      dc.renderAll() to draw the charts.
  }
```

The problem here, is that sometimes the page is not loaded as expected, and not a single chart is shown. Sometimes it's working, sometimes it's not.

I would love to be pointed into the right direction, as I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong. 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your ngOnInit method this way:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._dataService.getAllData()
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.data = JSON.stringify(data)

                let root = JSON.parse(this.data);
                let ndx = crossfilter(root);
                let all = ndx.groupAll();

            },
            error => this.errorMessage = < any > error
        )
}
```

This way you are sure that you use your `this.data` AFTER it has been given a value, this should work

Comment: Hi Gianluca,

Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the problem remains.
I changed my ngOnInit function like the way you said.
However, the component is still loaded without any charts sometimes.

Do you perhaps have any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you using OnPush ChangeDetectionStrategy?

Comment: No, I'm not.
What I do, is receive my data from my data service in the ngOnInit (like you told me). 

    data => {
                this.data = JSON.stringify(data)

                let root = JSON.parse(this.data);
                let ndx = crossfilter(root);
                let all = ndx.groupAll();
    }

In this same object, after let all = ndx.groupAll.
I also create multiple dimensions to filter on:

let someDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
          return d.sensorData.id;
        });
let someDimGroup = someDim.group()

After the dimensions,I call the dc.renderAll()

Comment: My html file contains 4 charts, defined like the following:
<div id="impactsChart" [ngBusy]="busy">
  <h4>Timeline</h4>
</div>

Comment: Check your console for javascript errors, maybe that is causing the crash

Comment: Yes, the charts have been working. The problem is that it's not consistent. one time its loaded perfectly, and the other time, I only get to see the <h4> title's from the html file. However, when logging info to the console, i do not get to see any errors

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: try to remove 
,error => this.errorMessage = < any > error

Comment: I got it working! Thank you for your help.
Apparantly there was a bug in my backend, which broke some of my data. Because of some rows in my data being broken, I could not draw the graphs.

Comment: Nice, the important thing is that you resolved your problem :)